# Webkit overflow scolling touch cannot applied on element that have function load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem from a week ago with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` that added on element that have load function. I tried a lot but i can't. I dont know what this problem is issue or not. 
This details from my problem for you :
I give just the example to be understanded
Example :

```
<div id="scroll" style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
window.onload = example();
function example(){
$('#scroll').load('example.php');
}
</script>
```

Please note code above is just example that i written here, but the problem is not far from that example.
Any solution will be appreciated :-)

Comment: `window.onload=example();` is the problem. correct syntax is `window.onload=example;`

Comment: I said code above is just example am i written here, because the problem is not about load function and example; The problem is about my title question. And i write example() is not have error on my project and will be load the page

Comment: nothing problem with example(); but if about file reader that  is problem and correct syntax example.